# Can't understand the last part of this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
i,j=min(a),max(a)
print(j-i,[(n*(n-1))//2,a.count(i)*a.count(j)][i!=j])
```

Can anyone explain last line?
I am guessing that it uses list comprehension but how? If my guess is wrong, then can you please describe what exactly one has used, with some reference or maybe syntax for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not list comprehension.  It's building a 2-element list, then taking advantage of `True==1` and `False==0` to index into the list.

A more Pythonic way to do it would be:

```
print(j-i,(n*(n-1))//2 if i==j else a.count(i)*a.count(j))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right on the point. His answer is more pythonic.

Just for future reference. Whenever I can't read a line right away, I try to rewrite it with a better format, perhaps adding new lines and indents.

```
print(
    j-i,
    [  (n*(n-1))//2,
       a.count(i)*a.count(j)  ][i!=j]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier i remove the input(). Replace it with "5" and "1 2 3 4 5"

## I think you understod this part

```
n=int("5") # n = 5
a=list(map(int,"1 2 3 4 5".split()))  # a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i,j=min(a),max(a)   # (i, j) = (1,5)
```

So now we have
n = 5; a =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; i=1; j=5;

Then we can start with [(n*(n-1))//2 ,a.count(i)*a.count(j)]:

```
x = (n*(n-1))//2 = 10
y = a.count(i)*a.count(j) = 1
```

```
[(n*(n-1))//2 ,a.count(i)*a.count(j)] = [x,y] = [10,1]
```

Now we put it into: print(j-i,[(n*(n-1))//2,a.count(i)*a.count(j)][i!=j])
print(j-i,[10,1][i!=j])
then we have:

```
k = j-i = 4
l = [10,1][i!=j] = 1

print(k,l)
```

This gives:

```
>>> print(4,1)
(4, 1)
```